# Error in converting datatype nvarchar to int

Tags: c#-4.0

I get an error of conversion of nvarchar to int. I also tried parsing but it does not solve my problem. So how do I solve that problem?? Please provide me solution.

Code in stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.IDMaker
    (@Name varchar(50) = '',
     @Address varchar(50) = '',
     @Contact int,
     @EmergencyContact int,
     @BloodGroup varchar(50) = '',
     @Disease varchar(50) = '',
     @Drug varchar(50) = '',
     @Operation varchar(50),
     @ID int = 0)   
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@Operation = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO IDRegis(Name, Address, Contact, EmergencyContact, BloodGroup, Disease, Drug) 
        VALUES (@Name, @Address, @Contact, @EmergencyContact, @BloodGroup, @Disease, @Drug)

        RETURN
    END
```

Code in Windows forms :

```
//int contact, emcontact;
//if (!Int32.TryParse(txtphone.Text, out contact))
//{
//    MessageBox.Show("Enter Valid number...");
//    return;
//}

//if (!Int32.TryParse(txtemphone.Text, out emcontact))
//{
//    MessageBox.Show("Enter Valid number...");
//    return;
//}

if (objmyclass.con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    objmyclass.con.Open();
}

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IDMaker", objmyclass.con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtadd.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtphone.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmergencyContact",txtemphone.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloodGroup", txtbg.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Disease", txted.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Drug", txtdrug.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operation", 1);

int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    

if (i > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Inserted....");
}
```

Comment: I have given connection in seprate class whose reference in this form is objmyclass

Comment: where is casting that you performed?

Comment: i have commented that code as i used int.parseInt32 befoe opening connection